# Material-UI makeStyles vs withStyles generated class names

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui, high-order-component

I've noticed that classes generated with **makeStyles** and the use of hooks follow this nomenclature:

[image: makeStyles]

while the classes generated with **withStyles** and the use of HOC follow this one:

[image]

Is there a way to use **makeStyles** (I like to use hooks) but keep the **nomenclature of withStyles**? I'd like this because it's easier to analyze the html in the browser and pinpoint the class that generated each element.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @RyanCogswell, I've just edited my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second (optional) argument to `makeStyles` is an object of options to control the behavior of `makeStyles`. One of the options is a [name](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui-styles/src/makeStyles/makeStyles.js#L188) which is then used as a prefix for the class names. `withStyles` [passes Component.displayName](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.11.4/packages/material-ui-styles/src/withStyles/withStyles.js#L41) as the `name` option. You can specify whatever name you want in order to control the class name prefix, for instance in my example below the class name ends up being `Hello-root-1`.

```
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles(
  {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: "green"
    }
  },
  { name: "Hello" }
);

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className={classes.root}>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit Control makeStyles class name prefix]

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I wanted