# How to know which makeStyles() call compiled a specific CSS class in Material UI?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, css-in-js

I have something like this:

```js
// Some document, let's name it A
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  someClass: {}
}));
```

```js
// Another document, let's name it B
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core";

export default makeStyles((theme) => ({
  someClass: {}
}));
```

When both A and B call `makeStyles`, two different CSS classes of the form `makeStyles-someClass-N` will be exported, with `N` being the only difference in their final identifier.

Is there a way to establish which of the two documents exported a specific CSS class name based on the value of `N`, or any other way to create a CSS sourcemap?

Comment: See my recent answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68091865/material-ui-makestyles-vs-withstyles-generated-class-names/68092234#68092234. The approach shown there lets you control the prefix so that it can be something other than `makeStyles`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it's a nice workaround, since adding the prefix to the suspect `makeStyles()` calls will decrease the time I spend debugging this type of cases. Thanks! :)

Comment: The value of N will in most cases correspond to the order in which the `makeStyles` calls occurred, but that may not always be helpful since the order in which files get imported/executed may not be obvious in a large codebase with lots of reuse items f components.